# Assign variable value to different bootstrap tab

Tags: vb.net, tabs, bootstrap-modal

I currently have a `script manager`, `update panel` and `content template`.
Within `content template`, I have `modal popup` and tabs within it.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
             <ContentTemplate>
         <div id="aboutModalTest" class="modal fade" tabindex="4" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#add" aria-controls="add" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Add</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ><a href="#confirm" aria-controls="confirm" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Confirm</a></li>
  </ul>
```

In the `add` tab, i have a form for users to sign up for membership. Upon filling up the form, users must go to the `confirm` tab, to verify input. What i am trying to do is to assign the input values to read-only controls in `confirm` tab.

May i get any directions on how can i go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to solve the question using the solution below.
I first set the second tab to read-only by removing `data-toggle="tab`.

```
 <ul id="navtabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#add" aria-controls="add" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Add</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ><a href="#confirm" aria-controls="confirm" role="tab">Confirm</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I have a button in the first table as follow:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" Text="Verify Entry" onclick="btnAdd_Click"/>
```

at the bottom of my aspx before `</body>`, i included the following and was able to pass the variable over. Upon clicking the button, it will pass the variable value over and focus on the second tab which is read-only.

```
<script>
         $(function () {

             $('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {

                 e.preventDefault();
                 var provider = document.getElementById("ddlNewProvider").value;

                 $('#navtabs a[href="#confirm"]').tab('show');


             })

         })
     </script>
```